# How to download and install .ipa outside App Store with .plist

Tags: ios, app-store, ipa

Today I discovered an app.

This app is not available to the App Store, if I want to try this, I just have to click on the link since my iPhone :

itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://*********.s3.amazonaws.com/********-ios.plist

And the application installs in my home page.

The link forced to download a .plist :

[image]

What it this way ?

What it's the deal with provisioning profile or the certificats ?

Comment: Note that what they are doing is a blatant violation of the terms of the Developer agreement (unless you are a beta tester for them and they have your UDID?)

Comment: No, He don't have my UDID.

Comment: @borrrden Probably you are right in this case. However, it's very nice to know how the links work. In our company we use it to distribute automatic builds to beta testers, using an Enteprise account. I believe TestFlight uses the same mechanism, too.

Comment: You might want to edit that image a little, even though you've blurred it it's still readable !

Comment: Hi , don't know if i'm late but would like to ask if we can download the app from a url by tis method without adding the UDID in certificate ?

Comment: @VivienCormier the blurred image is still visible in the edit history

Comment: Doesn't Apple require the HTML, the PLIST and the IPA to live on a server with an SSL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's just a way of distributing an app for beta testing using your distribution profile, but without submitting it to Apple.

The .plist it's just a link to where the .ipa (the app) is stored.

You can find a tutorial here:

[How to Distribute your iOS Apps Over the Air](http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air)

Comment: It's also a good example of violating Apple's policies: using Enterprise Distribution Profile for public distribution is not allowed.

Comment: Ok it's not a Good idea :)