# Direct Installation of .IPA file in iOS devices

Tags: ios

how websites like DIAWI, which helps installing .IPA file directly, works? I would like to install apps without depending third arty websites. I think if somebody helps i am able to implement it self.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download and install .ipa outside App Store with .plist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17543574/how-to-download-and-install-ipa-outside-app-store-with-plist)

Comment: I have tried the solution explained there but when i click on the link, which links to plist, i got an error "can't connect to server". What to do...pls help

Comment: Do u have a server where u have stored the ipa? If not you could try to use a public dropbox link. But remember to change teh plist link as well

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22851812/enterprise-application-download-cannot-connect-to-website-address-error

Comment: Thank u so much for ur great suggestions. I went through the information in that link. but it includes lots of questions there. I could not find a solution there. could u help me pls......

Comment: Here is an tutorial how to do it with dropbox: https://appsandhacksblog.wordpress.com/2015/05/17/ad-hoc-distribution-over-dropbox/.